# Dropdown Button Closing on every click anywhere on the drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, shopify

I made a dropdown that I took from templates on the internet. Here's what I've comed up with but is having a trouble. The problem is, everytime I'm clicking on each link on the dropdown, the dropdown closes. Here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //open/close mega-navigation
    $('.cd-dropdown-trigger').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        toggleNav();
    });

    //close meganavigation
    $('.cd-dropdown .cd-close').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        toggleNav();
    });

    //on mobile - open submenu
    $('.has-children').children('a').on('click', function(event){
        //prevent default clicking on direct children of .has-children 
        event.preventDefault();
        var selected = $(this);
        selected.next('ul').removeClass('is-hidden').end().parent('.has-children').parent('ul').addClass('move-out');
    });

    //on desktop - differentiate between a user trying to hover over a dropdown item vs trying to navigate into a submenu's contents
    var submenuDirection = ( !$('.cd-dropdown-wrapper').hasClass('open-to-left') ) ? 'right' : 'left';
    $('.cd-dropdown-content').menuAim({
        activate: function(row) {
            $(row).children().addClass('is-active').removeClass('fade-out');
            if( $('.cd-dropdown-content .fade-in').length == 0 ) $(row).children('ul').addClass('fade-in');
        },
        deactivate: function(row) {
            $(row).children().removeClass('is-active');
            if( $('li.has-children:hover').length == 0 || $('li.has-children:hover').is($(row)) ) {
                $('.cd-dropdown-content').find('.fade-in').removeClass('fade-in');
                $(row).children('ul').addClass('fade-out')
            }
        },
        exitMenu: function() {
            $('.cd-dropdown-content').find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
            return true;
        },
        submenuDirection: submenuDirection,
    });

    //submenu items - go back link
    $('.go-back').on('click', function(){
        var selected = $(this),
            visibleNav = $(this).parent('ul').parent('.has-children').parent('ul');
        selected.parent('ul').addClass('is-hidden').parent('.has-children').parent('ul').removeClass('move-out');
    }); 

    function toggleNav(){
        var navIsVisible = ( !$('.cd-dropdown').hasClass('dropdown-is-active') ) ? true : false;
        $('.cd-dropdown').toggleClass('dropdown-is-active', navIsVisible);
        $('.cd-dropdown-trigger').toggleClass('dropdown-is-active', navIsVisible);
        if( !navIsVisible ) {
            $('.cd-dropdown').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
                $('.has-children ul').addClass('is-hidden');
                $('.move-out').removeClass('move-out');
                $('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
            }); 
        }
    }

    //IE9 placeholder fallback
    //credits http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html
    if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
        $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
            }
        }).blur(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
            }
        }).blur();
        $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                }
            })
        });
    }
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
    <div class="cd-dropdown-wrapper nav-div cd-dropdown-trigger" href="#0" id="nav-icon2">

  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <nav class="cd-dropdown">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <a href="#0" class="cd-close">Close</a>
    <ul class="cd-dropdown-content">

      <li class="has-children"><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=748">Catalog</a>
        <ul class="cd-secondary-dropdown is-hidden">
          <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Menu</a></li>
          <li class="see-all"><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/pages/shop-travel-jackets-with-lots-of-pockets">All Products</a></li>
          <li class="has-children"><a href="">Travel Gear</a>
            <ul class="is-hidden">
              <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Clothing</a></li>
              <li class="has-children"><a href="#0">Soft Shell</a>
                <ul class="is-hidden">
                  <li class="go-back"><a href="#0"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/collections/soft-shell-gen1">Soft Shell Gen1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/collections/soft-shell-joey">Soft Shell Joey</a></li>
                  <li class="see-all"><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/collections/soft-shell-jackets">All Soft Shell Jackets</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="has-children"><a href="#0">Sweatshirts</a>
                <ul class="is-hidden">
                  <li class="go-back"><a href="#0"></a></li>
                  <li class="see-all"><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/collections/sweatshirt-travel-jackets">All Sweatshirt Jackets</a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/collections/sweatshirt-gen1">Sweatshirts Gen1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/collections/sweatshirt-joey">Sweatshirt Joey</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="has-children"><a href="#0">Polar Fleece</a>
                <ul class="is-hidden">
                  <li class="go-back"><a href="#0"></a></li>
                  <li class="see-all"><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/collections/polar-fleece">All Polar Fleece</a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/collections/polar-fleece/products/polar-fleece-liner">Polar Fleece Gen1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/collections/polar-fleece/products/joey-polar-fleece-zip-in-liner">Joey Polar Fleece</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/collections/windbreaker-travel-jackets">Windbreakers</a></li>

              <li><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/products/sleepmasktravelpillow">Travel Pillow</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- .cd-secondary-dropdown -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/pages/about-us-who-makes-these-travel-jackets">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/pages/frequently-asked-questions-about-travel-jackets">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://global-travel-clothing.myshopify.com/pages/affiliate-area-global-travel-clothing">Make Money Selling our Jackets</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- .cd-dropdown-content -->
  </nav>

  <!-- .cd-dropdown -->
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon2').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('open');

    });
  });
  $("document").ready(function() {

    $('#nav-icon2').on('click', function(e) {
      if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a open and close button, you should do a hide show. not a toggle. 
for instance have a button that adds a style or adds a class with the CSS display:none;

```
<div style="display:none;">Hidden Stuff</div>
```

then have a button that gives it the CSS property display:block;

```
<div style="display:block;">Shown Stuff</div>
```

but more importantly, its not included in the snippit but i thought i'd ask, do you include jQuery in the `<head>` tag of your index.html?

Comment: I'll try to make it work with your advice. Yes, I included jQuery.